# Group Multiple row data by comma separated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to group multiple rows in one field separated by commas.

I have CS ID, CS Name and CS Order in my table. My CS's can order multiple items and just want all those Order#'s to show in one field separated by columns.

```
SELECT 
  dbo.Tb1.CSID, 
  dbo.Tb2.CSName, 
  **dbo.Tb3.OrderNumber** 
FROM dbo.Tb1   
  LEFT OUTER JOIN bo.Tb3 ON dbo.Tb1.id = dbo.Tb3.CSID 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tb2 ON dbo.Tb1.CSID = dbo.Tb2.CSID 
WHERE dbo.Tb1.Tb1.CSStatus = 'Current') 
  AND (dbo.Tb3.OrderNumber IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY dbo.Tb1.CSName
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the order number string in a sub query in order to show all the orders for that ID.

Also as of right now this won't exclude customers with no orders, to do that you could wrap this whole query and add a where Order Is Not Null

The For xml path is from [Concatenating Row Values](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

**Note:** This is untested.

```
SELECT 
  dbo.Tb1.CSID, 
  dbo.Tb2.CSName, 
  ( SELECT OrderNumber + ', '
     FROM dbo.Tb3 sq
    WHERE sq.CSID = tb1.CSID
    FOR XML PATH('') ) AS Orders    
)
FROM dbo.Tb1 tb1  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tb2 ON dbo.Tb1.CSID = dbo.Tb2.CSID 
WHERE dbo.Tb1.Tb1.CSStatus = 'Current') 
  AND ( IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY dbo.Tb1.CSName
```

Comment: Where do I join Tb1 & Tb3 within the sub query? Just little confused on joins now between Tb1 & Tb3

Comment: There is no need to join unless you need some other field from tb3, The subquery is evaluated straight into the select.  This method is common if you want some values from a separate table but don't want the overhead of joining

Answer (score 0):

This solution is almost the same as JustinM:s with the difference that it removes the last comma.

```
SELECT 
  dbo.Tb1.CSID, 
  dbo.Tb2.CSName, 
  STUFF(( SELECT ',' +  OrderNumber
     FROM dbo.Tb3 
    WHERE dbo.Tb1.id = dbo.Tb3.CSID 
    FOR XML PATH('') ),1,1,'') AS Orders    
)
FROM dbo.Tb1 tb1  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tb2 ON dbo.Tb1.CSID = dbo.Tb2.CSID 
WHERE dbo.Tb1.Tb1.CSStatus = 'Current') 
  AND ( IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY dbo.Tb1.CSName
```

Comment: Ahh nice, that did not occur to me. +1